# Getting data out of Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember `1.13.9` an Ember-data `1.13.11` and struggling to have Ember Data do what I would like. As an example, I have a model called "goal" and a

```
goals: Ember.on('init', Ember.computed(function() {
  const {store} = this.getProperties('store');
  return store.findAll('goal');
})),
```

When this runs it does query the database and put the appropriate records into the store BUT getting them out of the store is my problem. I would have thought that once the Promise resolved that I'd be able to *iterate* over the array of results. Using the inspector I can see that at `clients.goals.content.content` (where *clients* is the name of the server I see this from the inspector:

[image]

First of all this is pretty deep into the structure. I was hoping Ember's "get" would allow me to simply say something like `data.get('content.0.id')` but this just comes back as *undefined*. Second of all the crazy structure continues in that each of these listed objects are **InternalModel** objects which only have the following structure to them:

[image]

Note that:

- there are two InternalModels, that is the right number (matches store results)
- the `id` property is available here
- there is an internal property called `_data` which has the other attributes of the record

Ok so in a completely hacky way I could pull out what I need but surely I shouldn't be writing code like:

```
_goals: Ember.on('init', function() {
  const {store} = this.getProperties('store');
  store.findAll('goal').then(data => {
    let result = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
      let record = item.get('data'); // this gets what's in _data apparently
      record.id = item.get('id');
      result.push(record);
    }
    this.set('goals', result);
}),
```

Yuck. What am I missing?

Comment: Omg, data is collection of models, why do you create another collection which is exactly the same?

Comment: I'm sure what I'm doing is wrong, hence the question, but I am not creating another collection which is exactly the same ... the 'data' property which I set once the promise is resolved is a working array of records but terribly ugly in its extraction.

Comment: Why do you access `data` property when you have all attributes directly in `record`? It's unclear for me. What is so special in using `goals` that you need to create another array? Where do you struggle with using that? I think it's missing part of question.

Comment: when I execute `let record = item.get('data');` I gain access to that attributes but *not* the `id`

Comment: `recordId = item.get('id');` Where's the problem?

Comment: You can see that that is the next line of my code, right? It's just a lot of work to pull a flat record out the store. I'm fairly certain that Ember's `get()` used to do all the heavy lifting ... I shouldn't have to dig into the ED data structure and then restructure the output.

Comment: I m not sure if I understand your problem but why not just `goals: DS.hasMany('goal', { async: true })` ?

Comment: @Kitler not following you ... are you talking about the model definition? There is not a hasMany relationship in this example. The model is for `goal` and the store can have many of them but the goal records are not referencing other goals.

Comment: If you want to get objects from the response BEFORE Ember serializes it internally, look at the `normalizeXXXX` methods on the serializer - specifically `normalizeResponse` - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeResponse - which will allow you to access keys on the payload easily, or iterate over it. You can just call `_super` to retain the 'default' behaviour alongside your own inspection/extraction.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert Ember model to plain object you can use [Model.serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_serialize) or [Model.toJSON](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON) methods.

**Update:**

If you need to not just extract the data from models but to access fetched models via computed property, there are several ways to implement it.

**1) Synchronous property** (collection):

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    goals: [],

    someProperty: Ember.computed('goals.@each', function () {
        var goals = this.get('goals');
        goals.forEach(goal => {
            console.log( goal.get('someProperty') );
        });
    })
});
```

Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.store.findAll('goal').then(goals => {
            controller.set('goals', goals);
        });
    }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each goals as |goal|}}
    {{log goal}}
{{/each}}
```

**2) Asynchronous property** (promise):

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    goals: Ember.computed(function () {
        var storeGoals = this.store.peekAll('goal') || [];
        if (storeGoals.length) {
            return RSVP.resolve(storeGoals);
        } else {
            return this.store.findAll('goal')
        }
    }),

    someProperty: Ember.computed('goals.@each', function () {
        var goals = this.get('goals').then(resolvedGoals => {
            resolvedGoals.forEach(goal => {
                console.log( goal.get('someProperty') );
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each goals as |goal|}}
    {{log goal}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to do that. I just want to be able to resolve records from the store without being forced to understand the internals of ember-data's data structure.

Comment: Hey @ken Did you get the solution. I'm facing the same problem. Couldn't access directly the model attributes instead I'm forced to access using the nested stuff as mentioned above

Comment: truth be told, i don't remember @nagarjuna . sorry I couldn't be more help.